# Using different icons based on json feature in OpenLayers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openlayers

I want to use a different icons based on one of the value of `positionTitle` in `locations.json` features.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "year_id": 630,
      "name": "Vincent",
      "properties": {
        "date": "1892-09-01",
        "popup": "SF-address unknown",
        "positionTitle": "Resident"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.396564,
          37.793135
        ]
      }
    },

etc.
```

and an icon:

```
var homeIcon = new Icon({
 src: './images/home.png',
});
```

the layer (updated based on @ivom suggestion):

```
new VectorLayer({
  title: 'Locations as points',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: urlLocJSON, // from line 28
    format: new GeoJSON(), // works with or without the comma
  }), // source
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    if(feature.get('positionTitle') === 'Proprietor') {
      iconType = restoIcon;
    } else if(feature.get('positionTitle') === 'Cook') {
      iconType = restoIcon;
    } else if(feature.get('positionTitle') === 'Resident') {
      iconType = homeIcon;
    } else {
      iconType = new Icon({
         src: '../stylesheets/images/dish.png', // TODO check path
         opacity: 0.5,
         scale: 1.0,
         size: 30,
        }); // restoIcon // change to ?
    // window.alert('iconType: ', iconType, '. restoIcon: ', restoIcon);
    }
    return [new Style({
      icon: iconType
    })];
  },
}),
```

From `feature` in the line `style: function(feature, resolutions {

```
dispatching_: {}
disposed_: false
eventTarget_: undefined
geometryChangeKey_: {target: Point, type: "change", listener: ƒ}
geometryName_: "geometry"
id_: undefined
listeners_: {change:geometry: Array(1), change: Array(1), propertychange: Array(1)}
ol_uid: "89"
pendingRemovals_: {}
revision_: 1
styleFunction_: undefined
style_: null
values_:
date: "1894-09-01"
geometry: Point {disposed_: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, …}
popup: "329 Jackson St"
positionTitle: "Resident"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: BaseObject
```

How do I get the correct icon into the style? Update: no errors now, but no icons either.

Beta site: https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/people/140 with default icon. The lines are another layer.

Comment: You can use style function like in this topic for stroke color:
[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126668/writing-style-function-in-openlayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126668/writing-style-function-in-openlayers)

Comment: @ivom Thank you. I'm working with your suggestion. I updated the layer description. I also changed the structure of `location.json` because `positionTitle` was appearing under values with the geometry. The page loads with no errors but the icons do not appear at all. I'm relearning what little I knew about JS debugging and maybe will find a clue.